# Why do we need a server for a ChatGPTPluginRetriever?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I try to use ChatGPT Retriever Plugin using LangChain library. [Here](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/retrievers/examples/chatgpt-plugin-retriever.html) are the instructions that I follow. This page contains the following example:

```
from langchain.retrievers import ChatGPTPluginRetriever
retriever = ChatGPTPluginRetriever(url="http://0.0.0.0:8000", bearer_token="foo")
retriever.get_relevant_documents("alice's phone number")
```

In the third line of the code we instantiate the retriever object by specifying an url. How do you think, does this line starts a server on the specified url or, instead, we just tell the retriever object to lisdten to this url?

I guess it is the second option (retriever should listen to a server). So, if it the case, how do we start the server that the retriever should listen to?

It is also not clear to me why do we need the server, since all the information that the retriever need is stored in the local `foo.json` file.